# How do I convert a std::chrono::time_point to long and back?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I need to convert `std::chrono::time_point` to and from a `long` type (integer 64 bits). I´m starting working with `std::chrono` ...

Here is my code:

```
int main ()
{
     std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto epoch = now.time_since_epoch();
    auto value = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(epoch);
    long duration = value.count();


    std::chrono::duration<long> dur(duration);

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dt(dur);

    if (dt != now)
        std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
}
```

This code compiles, but does not show success.

Why is `dt` different than `now` at the end?

What is missing on that code?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the chrono library, but I believe you have to use `std::chrono::duration<long,std::milli> dur` and even then, you might get rounding errors (`std::chrono::system_clock` has probably a higher resolution than milliseconds).

Comment: @MikeMB all clocks on reasonably new hardware should have somewhere around microsecond/sub-microsecond precision anyway. See an article titled [The Three Clocks](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_tP7xs9DpAhV8ITQIHamjAxIQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.modernescpp.com%2Findex.php%2Fthe-three-clocks&usg=AOvVaw2E-RgmLWttMk7B9jLbmt39). Really, windows will usually have higher precision with `system_clock` (around 100 times greater), but even this is usually sub-microsecond.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

This is a great place for `auto`:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

Since you want to traffic at `millisecond` precision, it would be good to go ahead and covert to it in the `time_point`:

```
auto now_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now);
```

`now_ms` is a `time_point`, based on `system_clock`, but with the precision of `milliseconds` instead of whatever precision your `system_clock` has.

```
auto epoch = now_ms.time_since_epoch();
```

`epoch` now has type `std::chrono::milliseconds`.  And this next statement becomes essentially a no-op (simply makes a copy and does not make a conversion):

```
auto value = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(epoch);
```

Here:

```
long duration = value.count();
```

In both your and my code, `duration` holds the number of `milliseconds` since the epoch of `system_clock`.

This:

```
std::chrono::duration<long> dur(duration);
```

Creates a `duration` represented with a `long`, and a precision of `seconds`.  This effectively `reinterpret_cast`s the `milliseconds` held in `value` to `seconds`.  It is a logic error.  The correct code would look like:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds dur(duration);
```

This line:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dt(dur);
```

creates a `time_point` based on `system_clock`, with the capability of holding a precision to the `system_clock`'s native precision (typically finer than milliseconds).  However the run-time value will correctly reflect that an integral number of milliseconds are held (assuming my correction on the type of `dur`).

Even with the correction, this test will (nearly always) fail though:

```
if (dt != now)
```

Because `dt` holds an integral number of `milliseconds`, but `now` holds an integral number of ticks finer than a `millisecond` (e.g. `microseconds` or `nanoseconds`).  Thus only on the rare chance that `system_clock::now()` returned an integral number of `milliseconds` would the test pass.

But you can instead:

```
if (dt != now_ms)
```

And you will now get your expected result reliably.

Putting it all together:

```
int main ()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now);

    auto value = now_ms.time_since_epoch();
    long duration = value.count();

    std::chrono::milliseconds dur(duration);

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dt(dur);

    if (dt != now_ms)
        std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
}
```

Personally I find all the `std::chrono` overly verbose and so I would code it as:

```
int main ()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    auto now_ms = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(now);

    auto value = now_ms.time_since_epoch();
    long duration = value.count();

    milliseconds dur(duration);

    time_point<system_clock> dt(dur);

    if (dt != now_ms)
        std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
}
```

Which will reliably output:

```
Success.
```

Finally, I recommend eliminating temporaries to reduce the code converting between `time_point` and integral type to a minimum.  These conversions are dangerous, and so the less code you write manipulating the bare integral type the better:

```
int main ()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    // Get current time with precision of milliseconds
    auto now = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
    // sys_milliseconds is type time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>
    using sys_milliseconds = decltype(now);
    // Convert time_point to signed integral type
    auto integral_duration = now.time_since_epoch().count();
    // Convert signed integral type to time_point
    sys_milliseconds dt{milliseconds{integral_duration}};
    // test
    if (dt != now)
        std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
}
```

The main danger above is *not* interpreting `integral_duration` as `milliseconds` on the way back to a `time_point`.  One possible way to mitigate that risk is to write:

```
    sys_milliseconds dt{sys_milliseconds::duration{integral_duration}};
```

This reduces risk down to just making sure you use `sys_milliseconds` on the way out, and in the two places on the way back in.

And one more example:  Let's say you want to convert to and from an integral which represents whatever duration `system_clock` supports (microseconds, 10<sup>*th*</sup> of microseconds or nanoseconds).  Then you don't have to worry about specifying milliseconds as above.  The code simplifies to:

```
int main ()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    // Get current time with native precision
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    // Convert time_point to signed integral type
    auto integral_duration = now.time_since_epoch().count();
    // Convert signed integral type to time_point
    system_clock::time_point dt{system_clock::duration{integral_duration}};
    // test
    if (dt != now)
        std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
}
```

This works, but if you run half the conversion (out to integral) on one platform and the other half (in from integral) on another platform, you run the risk that `system_clock::duration` will have different precisions for the two conversions.

Comment: @BrentNash: Careful, I might take you up on that. ;-)  I'll be at Cppcon 2015 (http://cppcon.org) talking about this:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html .  The subject is very closely related to the `time_point_cast<milliseconds>(now)` in my answer above.  Only the duration is courser:  `time_point_cast<days>(now)`.

Comment: Typo in last comment: coarser, not courser.   Great answer though.

Comment: The problem with English is that it isn't parsable with a C++ compiler, and the compiler makes a better spell checker. :-)

Comment: This is very helpful although I think it would have been a tab bit better if you had not been using 'auto' everywhere. Just for lazy people like me who would like to see what types are being manipulated without having to look elsewhere. Thanks a bunch @HowardHinnant

Comment: Just an observation: using `auto` in an example diminishes the value of the example a lot.

Comment: You should have just lead with "count()". Really. This is some real TL;DR just to get a bloody integral value. Also, as others have said, using auto diminishes the example, as others have said. IMO if one has to resort to auto very much then quite likely the library is too complex for the problem at hand. Much of what I've seen with std::chrono and co., it is just trafficking in a counter and a ratio. Why are these concepts being used in templates? Seems like overkill, more of the Committee's fetish for over-complicating stuff.

Comment: To go from `system_clock::now()` to `ms` since 1970 in a `long`:  `long i = system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()/1ms;`

Comment: `.count()` works too, if you throw in a `duration_cast<milliseconds>`.  That being said, the compiler will catch logic errors for at compile-time if you stay within the chrono type system for as long as possible.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59446610/576911

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought better of my O.P. didn't expect you to be answering it right away.

Comment: I hate it when I'm everywhere too. :-)  Hopefully helpful chrono video tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  It costs an hour.

Comment: IDK, I dunno. I see value in this stuff for locales. But if I am dealing in stuff like time since the UNIX epoch, this is like using a nuclear bomb when a bullet would do as well.

Comment: Some value a strong type system more than others.  Fwiw, this doesn't have much to do with locales, except maybe for converting localized strings into weekdays and months.  And C++11/14/17 chrono really doesn't help there anyway (it does in C++20).

Comment: Well, how many seconds or mS since the epoch *is* actually just a integer, eh?

Comment: The locale stuff though can be really hard to handle in older versions of C++, your stuff here for that is quite nice.

Comment: Two links highly recommended:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/59446610/576911  and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: @HowardHinnant  Good answer! What's `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dt(dur);` in your first example?If I understand you correctly,the `dt` is almost the same with `now`. Am I right? If I miss something, please let me know.

Comment: `dt` has the same type as `now`, but with a value truncated to milliseconds precision.  In this case the truncation is towards the epoch, which is in the past, so truncated to the beginning of the millisecond `now` is within.

Answer (score 11):

I would also note there are two ways to get the number of ms in the time point. I'm not sure which one is better, I've benchmarked them and they both have the same performance, so I guess it's a matter of preference. Perhaps Howard could chime in:

```
auto now = system_clock::now();

//Cast the time point to ms, then get its duration, then get the duration's count.
auto ms = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(now).time_since_epoch().count();

//Get the time point's duration, then cast to ms, then get its count.
auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(tpBid.time_since_epoch()).count();
```

The first one reads more clearly in my mind going from left to right.

Answer (score 8):

as a single line:

```
long value_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()).time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`time_point` objects](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/time_point/operators/) only support arithmetic with other `time_point` or `duration` objects.

You'll need to convert your `long` to a [`duration`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/duration/duration/) of specified units, then your code should work correctly.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Both of the provided links have an "Example" section at the bottom.

Comment: I made it compile, but there is some logic error... I´ve editted the original code...

Comment: It would benefit the answer to include examples. Links die or change. That being said, I'm not sure why this was downvoted.