# How do I get seconds since epoch as a double, given a time point?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I have a function from a library i'm using that requires a double as a parameter. It needs to be passed an offset of type nanoseconds plus the sytem_clock::now(). I have this code so far:

```
system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); 
    auto timepointoffset = (now + desiredOffset);
```

How can I make this a double?

Edit: So I need to add that the problem is that I need to do it without a risk of losing data. I have this code:

```
    system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); 
    auto timepointoffset =  std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now + desiredOffset);
    double value = timepointoffset.time_since_epoch().count();
```

The problem is that the compiler says that there is a possible loss of data.

Comment: You don't mention ntp in your question. How is it a relevant tag?

Comment: Did you try `double newTime = static_cast<double>(timepointoffset);` or something similar?

Comment: Matt, I did try that and it does not work.

Comment: long http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255486/c-how-do-i-convert-a-stdchronotime-point-to-long-and-back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time_point` template has a member function `time_point::time_since_epoch` that returns the time since epoch as a `duration` object. `duration` is a template type and the exact duration type returned by the function is the same as the `Duration` template parameter of the `time_point`. The type of `time_point` returned by `system_clock::now()` on the other hand is implementation defined.

You want the time in a specific representation. To achieve that, you must have the duration of the desired type. In this case, you want `std::duration<double, std::ratio<1>>`. To get the duration returned by `time_since_epoch`  in correct type, you can cast it using `std::chrono::duration_cast`. When you have  the duration of the correct representation, you can use the `count` member function of `duration` to get the value in the desired representation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe I did as you said, but I am still getting a warning that there is a possible loss of data. Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: @Elijah maybe you are, or maybe there is something else wrong with your code. The exact warning message and the line that it points to should reveal what's wrong.

Answer (score 10):

This program:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto tp = system_clock::now() + 0ns;
    double t1 = tp.time_since_epoch().count();
    double t2 = std::nextafter(t1, INFINITY);
    std::cout << t2-t1 << '\n';
}
```

currently outputs:

```
256
```

This means that currently a double can not exactly represent the number of nanoseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  A double can represent a unit equal to 256ns (about a quarter of a microsecond).

This has been true since 2006-07-14 23:58:24.606847232.  Before then (for a while), a double could represent with a precision of 128ns.

At 2043-01-25 23:56:49.213694464 UTC a double will start being able to represent a precision of only 512ns.

A double can store a `system_clock::time_point` with nanosecond precision only in the approximate range of 1969-09-18 18:00:01 to 1970-04-15 05:59:59.

This analysis of course assumes an IEEE 64 bit double.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
  std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << std::endl;
```

appears to be the correct way to get a long: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch which you can then convert to double.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `timepointoffset` to `std::time_t` and then cast it to double:

```
std::time_t offsetTimet = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(timepointoffset);
double offsetDouble = static_cast<double>(offsetTimet);
```

Be aware that while `std::time_t` is normally an integer type, [there is no guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792551/what-primitive-data-type-is-time-t).

Answer (score 0):

> So I need to add that the problem is that I need to do it without a risk of losing data. I have this code:

There is no way to do this in general.  When you convert from an integer type to a floating point type, you will typically lose precision.  Using [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), the bits are split into a mantissa and an exponent.  Since an integer has no bits allocated for an exponent, there are generally fewer bits of precision to represent the value.

For example, converting from `int64_t` to `double`.  An `int64_t` has 1 sign bit, and 63 value bits.  A double has 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits, and 52 mantissa bits.  So converting from `int64_t` (63) to `double` (52), you can lose up to 11 bits of information.