# How to change type of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); to long?

Tags: c++, clock, c++-chrono

```
t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

long t = t_start; //error
```

Furthermore, I cannot add **t_start** with **t_end**.

```
t_start += t_end; //error
```

Comment: Don't store it as a long. store it as a `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`. What are you really trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ How do I convert a std::chrono::time\_point to long and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255486/c-how-do-i-convert-a-stdchronotime-point-to-long-and-back)

Comment: I am trying to calculate wall time for each time I call a function.

Comment: Why do you need to add two time points? The difference between times is what normally matters.
Can you explain more about your intended usage?

Comment: I was using this function for calculating wall time, but for multithreaded environment I want to change it to calculate wall time and cpu time. For cpu time I am using  std::clock and for wall time std::chrono micro. For this program, I am calculating both time as I start the program and than just subtract that amount whenever I call this function to calculate both times between          void get_wall_time(uintmax_t* wall_time, long* wall_time_ns) {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    *wall_time = uintmax_t(ts.wall_time);
    *wall_time_ns = ts.wall_time_ns;
       }

Comment: Also, becuase I cannot change the type to long I am not sure how to pass the value by reference. the new function looks like this: void get_wall_time(uintmax_t* wall_time, long* wall_time_ns) {
  
    c_end = std::clock();
    t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

     uintmax_t tt = 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   
    long time_span = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end - t_start).count();
         
   
  }

Comment: Please refrain from writing extensive code in comments.  Instead you should edit your question to show the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to *add* two time points, one operand should be a duration. Consider the following sentences:

> Add "1523439002.733219701 seconds since 1 Jan 1970" to "1523439842.733219701 seconds since 1 Jan 1970"
>
> Add "500 seconds" to "523439842.733219701 seconds since 1 Jan 1970"
>
> Add "523439842.733219701 seconds since 1 Jan 1970" to "500 seconds"
>
> Add "500 seconds" to "1000 seconds"

From your comments, what you *actually* want is to pass time points around. Just change the code that accepts `long`s to accept `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`s