# Gaffer on games timestep: std::chrono implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, game-engine, c++-chrono, game-loop

If you're not familiar with the Gaffer on Games article "Fix your Timestep", you can find it here:
https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

I'm building a game engine, and in an effort to get more comfortable with std::chrono I've been trying to implement a fixed time step using std::chrono for.. a couple of days now and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Here is the pseudo-code I'm working towards:

```
double t = 0.0;
double dt = 0.01;

double currentTime = hires_time_in_seconds();
double accumulator = 0.0;

State previous;
State current;

while ( !quit )
{
    double newTime = time();
    double frameTime = newTime - currentTime;
    if ( frameTime > 0.25 )
        frameTime = 0.25;
    currentTime = newTime;

    accumulator += frameTime;

    while ( accumulator >= dt )
    {
        previousState = currentState;
        integrate( currentState, t, dt );
        t += dt;
        accumulator -= dt;
    }

    const double alpha = accumulator / dt;

    State state = currentState * alpha + 
        previousState * ( 1.0 - alpha );

    render( state );
}
```

**Goals:**

- I don't want rendering to be frame-rate bound. I should render in the busy loop
- I want a fully fixed time-step where I call my update function with a `float` delta time
- No sleeps

My current attempt (semi-fixed):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <SDL.h>

namespace {
    using frame_period = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 60>>;
    const float s_desiredFrameRate = 60.0f;
    const float s_msPerSecond = 1000;
    const float s_desiredFrameTime = s_msPerSecond / s_desiredFrameRate;
    const int s_maxUpdateSteps = 6;
    const float s_maxDeltaTime = 1.0f;
}


auto framePrev = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto frameCurrent = framePrev;

auto frameDiff = frameCurrent - framePrev;
float previousTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
while (m_mainWindow->IsOpen())
{

    float newTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
    float frameTime = newTicks - previousTicks;
    previousTicks = newTicks;

    // 32 ms in a frame would cause this to be .5, 16ms would be 1.0
    float totalDeltaTime = frameTime / s_desiredFrameTime;

    // Don't execute anything below
    while (frameDiff < frame_period{ 1 })
    {
        frameCurrent = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        frameDiff = frameCurrent - framePrev;
    }

    using hr_duration = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration;
    framePrev = std::chrono::time_point_cast<hr_duration>(framePrev + frame_period{ 1 });
    frameDiff = frameCurrent - framePrev;

    // Time step
    int i = 0;
    while (totalDeltaTime > 0.0f && i < s_maxUpdateSteps)
    {
        float deltaTime = std::min(totalDeltaTime, s_maxDeltaTime);
        m_gameController->Update(deltaTime);
        totalDeltaTime -= deltaTime;
        i++;
    }

    // ProcessCallbackQueue();
    // ProcessSDLEvents();
    // m_renderEngine->Render();
}
```

**Problems with this implementation**

- Rendering, handling input, etc is tied to the frame rate
- I'm using SDL_GetTicks() instead of std::chrono

**My actual question**

- How can I replace `SDL_GetTicks()` with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`? It seems like no matter what I need to use `count()` but I read from Howard Hinnant himself this quote:

> If you use count(), and/or you have conversion factors in your chrono code, then you're trying too hard.
>   So I thought maybe there was a more intuitive way.

- How can I replace all the `float`s with actual std::chrono_literal time values except for the end where I get the float deltaTime to pass into the update function as a modifier for the simulation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Below I implement a couple of different versions of "final touch" from [Fix your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) using `<chrono>`.  My hope is that this example will translate to your desired code.

The main challenge is figuring out what unit each `double` represents in [Fix your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/).  Once that is done, the transformation to `<chrono>` is fairly mechanical.

**Front matter**

So that we can easily change out the clock, start with a `Clock` type, for example:

```
using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
```

Later I'll show that one can even have `Clock` be implemented in terms of `SDL_GetTicks()` if desired.

If you have control over the signature of the `integrate` function, I recommend double-based seconds units for the time parameters:

```
void
integrate(State& state,
          std::chrono::time_point<Clock, std::chrono::duration<double>>,
          std::chrono::duration<double> dt);
```

This will allow you to pass anything you want in (as long the `time_point` is based on `Clock`), and not have to worry about explicit casting to the correct units.  Plus physics computations are often done in floating point, so this lends itself to that as well.  For example if `State` simply holds an acceleration and a velocity:

```
struct State
{
    double acceleration = 1;  // m/s^2
    double velocity = 0;  // m/s
};
```

and `integrate` is supposed to compute the new velocity:

```
void
integrate(State& state,
          std::chrono::time_point<Clock, std::chrono::duration<double>>,
          std::chrono::duration<double> dt)
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    state.velocity += state.acceleration * dt/1s;
};
```

The expression `dt/1s` simply converts the `double`-based chrono `seconds` into a `double` so it can participate in the physics computation.

`std::literals` and `1s` are C++14.  If you are stuck at C++11, you can replace these with `seconds{1}`.

**Version 1**

```
using namespace std::literals;
auto constexpr dt = 1.0s/60.;
using duration = std::chrono::duration<double>;
using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<Clock, duration>;

time_point t{};

time_point currentTime = Clock::now();
duration accumulator = 0s;

State previousState;
State currentState;

while (!quit)
{
    time_point newTime = Clock::now();
    auto frameTime = newTime - currentTime;
    if (frameTime > 0.25s)
        frameTime = 0.25s;
    currentTime = newTime;

    accumulator += frameTime;

    while (accumulator >= dt)
    {
        previousState = currentState;
        integrate(currentState, t, dt);
        t += dt;
        accumulator -= dt;
    }

    const double alpha = accumulator / dt;

    State state = currentState * alpha + previousState * (1 - alpha);
    render(state);
}
```

This version keeps everything almost exactly the same from [Fix your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/), except some of the `double`s get changed to type `duration<double>` (if they represent time durations), and others get changed to `time_point<Clock, duration<double>>` (if they represent points in time).

`dt` has units of `duration<double>` (double-based seconds), and I presume that the 0.01 from [Fix your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) is a type-o, and the desired value is 1./60.  In C++11 `1.0s/60.` can be changed to `seconds{1}/60.`.

local type-aliases for `duration` and `time_point` are set up to use `Clock` and `double`-based seconds.

And from here on out, the code is nearly identical to [Fix your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/), except for using `duration` or `time_point` in place of `double` for types.

Note that `alpha` is not a unit of time, but a dimension-less `double` coefficient.

> - How can I replace SDL_GetTicks() with std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()? It seems like no matter what I need to use count()

As above.  There is no use of `SDL_GetTicks()` nor `.count()`.

> - How can I replace all the floats with actual std::chrono_literal time values except for the end where I get the float deltaTime to pass into the update function as a modifier for the simulation?

As above, and you don't need to pass a float `delaTime` to the update function unless that function signature is out of your control.  And if that is the case, then:

```
m_gameController->Update(deltaTime/1s);
```

**Version 2**

Now let's go a little further:  Do we really need to use floating point for the duration and time_point units?

Nope.  Here's how you can do the same thing with integral-based time units:

```
using namespace std::literals;
auto constexpr dt = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 60>>{1};
using duration = decltype(Clock::duration{} + dt);
using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<Clock, duration>;

time_point t{};

time_point currentTime = Clock::now();
duration accumulator = 0s;

State previousState;
State currentState;

while (!quit)
{
    time_point newTime = Clock::now();
    auto frameTime = newTime - currentTime;
    if (frameTime > 250ms)
        frameTime = 250ms;
    currentTime = newTime;

    accumulator += frameTime;

    while (accumulator >= dt)
    {
        previousState = currentState;
        integrate(currentState, t, dt);
        t += dt;
        accumulator -= dt;
    }

    const double alpha = std::chrono::duration<double>{accumulator} / dt;

    State state = currentState * alpha + previousState * (1 - alpha);
    render(state);
}
```

There is really very little that has changed from Version 1:

- `dt` now has the value 1, represented by a `long long`, and has units of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>60</sub> of a second.
- `duration` now has a strange type that we don't even have to know the details about.  It is the same type as the resultant sum of a `Clock::duration` and `dt`.  This will be the coarsest precision that can exactly represent both a `Clock::duration` and <sup>1</sup>/<sub>60</sub> of a second.  Who cares what it is.  What is important is that the time-based arithmetic will have no truncation error, or not even any round-off error if `Clock::duration` is integral-based.  (Who said that one can not exactly represent <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> on a computer?!)
- The `0.25s` limit gets transformed instead into `250ms` (`milliseconds{250}` in C++11).
- The computation of `alpha` should aggressively convert to double-based units to avoid the truncation associated with integral-based division.

**More about `Clock`**

- Use `steady_clock` if you don't need to map `t` to a calendrical time in your physics, and/or you don't care if `t` slowly drifts away from the exact physical time.  No clock is perfect, and `steady_clock` never gets adjusted to the correct time (such as by an NTP service).
- Use `system_clock` if you need to map `t` to a calendrical time, or if you want `t` to stay in sync with UTC.  This will require a few small (probably millisecond-level or smaller) adjustments to `Clock` as the game plays.
- Use `high_resolution_clock` if you don't care whether you get `steady_clock` or `system_clock` and want to be surprised which you get each time you port your code to a new platform or compiler. :-)
- Finally, you can even stick with `SDL_GetTicks()` if you want by writing your own `Clock` like this:

E.g.:

```
struct Clock
{
    using duration = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    using rep = duration::rep;
    using period = duration::period;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = true;

    static
    time_point
    now() noexcept
    {
        return time_point{duration{SDL_GetTicks()}};
    }
};
```

Switching between:

- `using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;`
- `using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;`
- `using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;`
- `struct Clock {...};  // SDL_GetTicks based`

requires **zero** changes to the event loop, the physics engine, or the render engine.  Just recompile.  Conversion constants get updated automatically.  So you can easily experiment with which `Clock` is best for your application.

**Appendix**

My full `State` code for completeness:

```
struct State
{
    double acceleration = 1;  // m/s^2
    double velocity = 0;  // m/s
};

void
integrate(State& state,
          std::chrono::time_point<Clock, std::chrono::duration<double>>,
          std::chrono::duration<double> dt)
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    state.velocity += state.acceleration * dt/1s;
};

State operator+(State x, State y)
{
    return {x.acceleration + y.acceleration, x.velocity + y.velocity};
}

State operator*(State x, double y)
{
    return {x.acceleration * y, x.velocity * y};
}

void render(State state)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    static auto t = time_point_cast<seconds>(steady_clock::now());
    static int frame_count = 0;
    static int frame_rate = 0;
    auto pt = t;
    t = time_point_cast<seconds>(steady_clock::now());
    ++frame_count;
    if (t != pt)
    {
        frame_rate = frame_count;
        frame_count = 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Frame rate is " << frame_rate << " frames per second.  Velocity = "
              << state.velocity << " m/s\n";
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much for taking the time to reply! This is seriously awesome! I never knew std::chrono could look so clean! All of the std::chrono stuff makes perfect sense now, thank you again!

I do have full control over integrate and i'm on latest MSVC. I have a question around the State object. Do you suppose that `State state = currentState * alpha + previousState * (1 - alpha)` would expand to performing that operation on both `state.acceleration` and `state.velocity`? I wasn't sure if an `operator=` overload that can perform that operation was implied

Comment: Glad I could help.  On `State`, yes, the interpolation can operate on both fields.  I did so in my prototype.  I've added all of my `State` code to my answer to serve as an example.

Comment: Do you know what the 250ms stands for?

Comment: `250ms` is another way to write `milliseconds{250}`.  The syntax requires C++14 or better, and `using namespace std::chrono_literals;`.

Comment: @Lukas__: `250ms` is the limit put in place on the frame time to cope with the `spiral of death`. It doesn't have to be `250ms` exactly but it should be sufficiently high enough to deal with (hopefully temporary) spikes in load.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Nice work! This is the most comprehensive, complete and `true to form` C++ implementation I have seen of Gaffer's Fix Your Timestep. Your liberal use of the `chrono` library was especially enlightening. If I had to nitpick anything it'd be that the `integrate` function is incomplete (`t` is passed but isn't named or used) and on that note it should probably be made known that [Integration Basics](https://gafferongames.com/post/integration_basics/) really is required reading.