# Not sure my delta time function in C++ has the right logic

Tags: c++, logic, c++-chrono

I've been working on making a basic game loop in C++ and I'm unsure my logic is completely right as my delta time isn't what I expect. I expect to get 1/60 seconds per frame as my cap is 60fps, but over the average I take I get a delta time of ~0.03 seconds per frame giving me 33fps. I know the program can run faster than this as if I raise the frame cap it has a smaller delta time, which is still inaccurate. Any help? (I've removed unimportant bits of code to focus on the logic)

```
using namespace std::chrono;

int main(void)
{   
    //Init time - start and end, with delta time being the time between each run of the loop
    system_clock::time_point startTime = system_clock::now();
    system_clock::time_point endTime = system_clock::now();
    float deltaTime = 0.0f;

    //*Game made here*
  
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (window is not closed)
    {  
        //Takes time at start of loop
        startTime = system_clock::now();
        deltaFrameCount++;

        //Handle game processes

        //Get time at end of game processes
        endTime = system_clock::now();

        //Take time during work period
        duration<double, std::milli> workTime = endTime - startTime;

        //Check if program took less time to work than the cap
        if (workTime.count() < (milliseconds per frame cap))
        {
            //Works out time to sleep for by casting to double
            duration<double, std::milli> sleepDurationMS((milliseconds per frame cap) - workTime.count());
            //Casts back to chrono type to get sleep time
            auto sleepDuration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(sleepDurationMS);
            //Sleeps this thread for calculated duration
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(sleepDuration.count()));
        }

        //get time at end of all processes - time for one whole cycle
        endTime = system_clock::now();
        duration<double, std::milli> totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        deltaTime = (totalTime / 1000.0f).count();
    }

    //cleans game
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I expect to get 1/60 seconds per frame as my cap is 60fps, but over the average I take I get a delta time of ~0.03 seconds per frame giving me 33fps." - But how many FPS are you getting? You know your cap (60), but can you measure with an external tool your FPS count?

Comment: From [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for): "This function may block for longer than sleep_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays." In other words, sleep_for only guarantees to wait at least the specified amount of time but may wait longer depending on the scheduler. If you need exact delays, you may employ busy waiting or in case of a game with graphics, VSYNC.

Comment: @eike You're right, so I'm setting the frame cap to be higher at about 200fps which still has low impact but renders at a better framrate

Comment: A good read in this area: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59441699/576911