Why is the internal representation of chrono clocks typical nanoseconds and not directly the hardware counter
I have an embedded system where I want the now() method of my clocks to be as fast as possible. I intent to let the clock have an internal representation that matches the frequency of my hardware counter. That way a call to now() will not do any calculations.
But when I look at the implementation of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock in both Microsoft Visual C++ and GCC, I see than they implement the clocks with an internal representation of nanoseconds. The now() method then translates the hardware counter to nanosecond.
What is the reason for doing this? Am I on an unreasonable path making the internal representation match the hardware counter?

If you want bare counts then the intrinsic rdtsc will provide them raw - see how to get the CPU cycle count in x86. Only valid on x86 architectures.

Hardware clock ticks are runtime specific, on diffrent machines where application is deployed basic unit of time can be different (on MSVC _Query_perf_frequency() can return different values). Clocks in chrono library have fixed compile time representation.

Took me a while to find this(read the accepted answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441699/gaffer-on-games-timestep-stdchrono-implementation/59446610#59446610

For an embedded system, it's perfectly reasonable to use the native clock's actual tick interval.
The standard library implementations are designed to be a little more general because they could (in theory) be used on different types of hardware that use different clock rates.  Presenting the time in a well-known unit of time (rather than ticks), is a convenience to library users.  Nanoseconds, in particular, are small enough that you won't lose (much) precision when converting common clock rates to time.  At the same time, they're large enough that a wide range of times and durations can be represented in a reasonable number of bits.

No issue at all.
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now must (per the Standard) return a std::chrono::time_point, but no one says this time_point must be in nanoseconds.
In fact, this is a class template with its unit as a template parameter:
template<
    class Clock,
    class Duration = typename Clock::duration
> class time_point;

Per default, Duration is whatever duration defined in your clock's duration member, but it can be overriden by the duration you want.
This parameter is expected to be:
template<
    class Rep,
    class Period = std::ratio<1>
> class duration;

and you can make ratio whatever your hardware counter is.
See:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration


Full dummy example
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

struct evil_clock
{
    using duration = std::chrono::duration<unsigned long long, std::ratio<1, 666>>;

    auto static now()
    {
        static duration::rep counter{};
        return std::chrono::time_point<evil_clock>{duration{counter++}};
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, decltype(evil_clock::now()) time)
{
    std::cout << time.time_since_epoch();
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    for (int n = 0 ; n < 10 ; ++n) {
        std::cout << evil_clock::now() << '\n';
    }
}

demo

It's not specified what the duration of the high resolution clock should be, but in a Posix-system, using nanoseconds comes naturally since that's what you'll get by using the standard timespec with the Posix ::clock_gettime function which populates the timespec with whole seconds + nanoseconds. In a chrono clock, one then just have to create a duration since the epoch by adding the nanoseconds to the seconds and turn them into a time_point.
An example of what a now() implementation could look like:
namespace chrono {
namespace detail {

template <class Clock, clockid_t CLOCK_ID>
struct clock_base {
    using duration = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using rep = duration::rep;
    using period = duration::period;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<Clock, duration>;

    static time_point now() noexcept {
        std::timespec tp{};
        static_cast<void>(::clock_gettime(CLOCK_ID, &tp));

        // add nanoseconds to seconds and create a `time_point`:
        return time_point(duration(std::chrono::seconds(tp.tv_sec) +
                                   std::chrono::nanoseconds(tp.tv_nsec)));
    }
};

}  // namespace detail

struct system_clock : public detail::clock_base<system_clock, CLOCK_REALTIME> {
    // clock specific member functions ...
};
using high_resolution_clock = system_clock;

}  // namespace chrono

