# How to compare two datetime structures in C++ efficiently?

Tags: c++, datetime, struct, timestamp

I have the following DateTime structure:

```
struct DateTime
{
    std::uint16_t year;
    std::uint8_t month;
    std::uint8_t day;
    std::uint8_t hour;
    std::uint8_t minute;
    std::uint8_t second;
    std::uint16_t milisecond;
};
```

My doubt is about the **LessThan** and **GreaterThan** methods. I have implemented as follows in order to avoid a bunch of **ifs** and **elses**, but I might have not covered all possible situations:

```
bool GreaterThan(const DateTime& datetime)
{
    bool greater{true};

    // When found a different value for the most significant value, the evaluation is interrupted
    if ((year <= datetime.year) && (month <= datetime.month || year < datetime.year) &&
        (day <= datetime.day || month < datetime.month) && (hour <= datetime.hour || day < datetime.day) &&
        (minute <= datetime.minute || hour < datetime.hour) &&
        (second <= datetime.second || minute < datetime.minute) &&
        (milisecond <= datetime.milisecond || second < datetime.second))
    {
        greater = false;
    }

    return greater;
}

bool LessThan(const DateTime& datetime)
{
    bool less{true};

    // When found a different value for the most significant value, the evaluation is interrupted
    if ((year >= datetime.year) && (month >= datetime.month || year > datetime.year) &&
        (day >= datetime.day || month > datetime.month) && (hour >= datetime.hour || day > datetime.day) &&
        (minute >= datetime.minute || hour > datetime.hour) &&
        (second >= datetime.second || minute > datetime.minute) &&
        (milisecond >= datetime.milisecond || second > datetime.second))
    {
        less = false;
    }

    return less;
}
```

Please, let me know which possible situation is not covered.

Comment: Why not use `std::chrono::time_point` ? it has comparison operators already built it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_cmp.

Comment: OK. Just because I think who thinks in C has more chances to implement this stuff by scratch. Someone who only thinks in C++ would immediately talk about stuff like std::chrono... However, thank you for the advise.

Comment: What do you mean "only thinks in C++", though? Your code is literally using the `std` namespace, which is specific to C++ (and does not exist in C). You should therefore tag C and not C++. There is no C here, in this question.

Comment: @wohlstad, do you have milliseconds in `std::chrono::time_point`?

Comment: @Maf I'm not wohlstad, but yes, there are milliseconds.

Comment: Yes `std::chrono::time_point` contains milliseconds.

Comment: I didn't find such information here, I'm only seeing the timestamp until seconds: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point

Comment: Use: `return std::tie(year, month, day, hour, minute, milisecond) < std::tie(rhs.year, rhs.month, rhs.day, rhs.hour, rhs.minute, rhs.milisecond);`

Comment: @Maf - regarding milliseconds see the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255486/how-do-i-convert-a-stdchronotime-point-to-long-and-back.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post the std::tie answer so that I can accept it as the best?

Comment: @Mat the only "seconds" explicitly mentioned in that cppreference [time_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) page are microseconds (right before millisecond and whole seconds, in the end of the page)

Comment: Nice. If we have microseconds that's great. Thanks.

Comment: In c++20, `auto operator<=>(const DateTime&) const = default;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From all the comments, I think the best solution was proposed by –
**Richard Critten**:

```
bool GreaterThan(const DateTime& date_time)
{
    return (std::tie(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, milisecond) > 
            std::tie(date_time.year, date_time.month, date_time.day, date_time.hour, date_time.minute, date_time.second, date_time.milisecond));
}

bool LessThan(const DateTime& date_time)
{
    return (std::tie(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, milisecond) <
            std::tie(date_time.year, date_time.month, date_time.day, date_time.hour, date_time.minute, date_time.second, date_time.milisecond));
}
```

Comment: Even though this is arguably best, [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) has to create a temporary `std::tuple` objects(l-value refs) in each call of these functions. Considering the number of arguments passed to `std::tie`, better to have benchmark, prior to the production code.

Comment: Have you checked that the temporary is not optimised away ?

Answer (score 7):

Your implementation looks overly painful. There's a simpler, logical way to acheive this. If you know of the greedy algorithm, its a similar thought process to that.

```
bool GreaterThan(const datetime& datetime)
{
    if(year != datetime.year) return year > datetime.year;
    if(month != datetime.month) return month > datetime.month;
    //... and so on (omitted)
    return false; // they are the same
}
```

You can implement `LessThan` similarly.

Comment: And [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) will do it all for you, see comment above.

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh wow. I did not know about `std::tie`. Wow, I've been writing it the slow way all my programming career...

Comment: @RichardCritten Looks like `make_tuple` could work as well, right? In this case?

Comment: `std::make_tuple` will copy, `std::tie` creates a tuple of references.

Comment: I was about to post this answer last week. How could I wait too much? I'd have learnt this from you ASAP. Thanks a lot. I tested and std::tie is great!!!